# How to set up <text> element in d3, to fill all remaining space of its parent?

Tags: d3.js, orgchart

folks!
I am creating an app using unicef/react-org-chart based on d3. I'm doing some customisation, and I have a problem with width of a text element. It basically contains last and first name, job title etc. But the problem is that it splice entire string of last and first name, and split it into two tspan element inside text element, and  so creating new line under it and overflow text of job title. The parent container has enough space to include whole text, but it is just limiting of about 116px.
Does anybody know how to set a with of text container, and preserve wrapping of tspan.
Thanks

```js
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function (d) {
      var text = d3.select(this),
        words = d.person.name.split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr('y'),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
        tspan = text
          .text(null)
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', y)
          .attr('dy', dy + 'em')

      while ((word = words.pop())) {
        line.push(word)
        tspan.text(['Hello', 'World World World!'].join(' '))

        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop()
          tspan.text(line.join(' '))
          line = [word]
          tspan = text
            .append('tspan')
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', y)
            .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
            .text(word)
        }
      }
    })
  }

nodeEnter
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', PERSON_NAME_CLASS + ' unedited')
    .attr('x', namePosition.x)
    .attr('y', namePosition.y)
    .attr('dy', '.3em')
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style('fill', nameColor)
    .style('font-size', 14)
    .style('width', 200)
    .attr('width', 200)
    .call((d) => {
      wrap(d, 200)
    })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using foreignObjects instead of text elements? It allows you to use HTML divs, which has all the native support for text wrappers

Comment: @RodrigoDivino. No, I am completely new in it. I'll do resource for it. Thanks